# Trouble With Rhyming Algorithm Scala

Tags: scala

I want to make a method that takes two List of strings representing the sounds(phonemes & vowels) of two words as parameters. The function of this method is to determine whether or not the words rhyme based on the two sounds.

Definition of a rhyme: The words rhymes if the last vowel(inclusive) and after are the same. Words will rhyme even if the last vowel sounds have different stress. *Only vowels will have stress levels(numbers)*

My approach so far is to reverse the list so that the sounds are in reverse order and then add everything from the start of the line to the first vowel(inclusive). Then compare the two list to see if they equal. Please apply basic code, Im only at elementary level of scala. Just finished learning program execution.

Ex1: two words GEE and NEE will rhyme because GEE sound (“JH”,”IY1”) becomes (”IY1”,”JH”) and NEE sound (“N”,”IY1) becomes (”IY1”, “N”) since they have the same vowel everything else after should not be considered any more.

Ex2: two words GEE and JEEP will not rhyme because GEE sound (“JH”,”IY1”) becomes (”IY1”,”JH”) and JEEP sound (“JH”,”IY1”,”P”) becomes (”P”,”IY1”,”JH”) since the first sound in GEE is a vowel it’s being compared to “P” and “IY1” in JEEP.

Ex3: two words HALF and GRAPH will rhyme because HALF sound(“HH”,”AE1”,”F”) becomes (“F”,”AE1”,”HH”) and GRAPH sound (“G”,”R”,”AE2”,”F”) become (“F”,”AE2”,”R”,”G”) in this case although the first vowel have different stress(numbers) we ignore the stress since the vowels are the same.

```
def isRhymeSounds(soundList1: List[String], soundList2: List[String]): Boolean={
    val revSound1 = soundList1.reverse
    val revSound2 = soundList2.reverse
    var revSoundList1:List[String] = List()
    var revSoundList2:List[String] = List()
    for(sound1 <- revSound1) {
      if(sound1.length >= 3) {
        val editVowel1 = sound1.substring(0,2)
        revSoundList1 = revSoundList1 :+ editVowel1
      }
      else {
        revSoundList1 = revSoundList1 :+ sound1
      }
    }
    for(sound2 <- revSound2) {
      if(sound2.length >= 3) {
        val editVowel2 = sound2.substring(0, 2)
        revSoundList2 = revSoundList2 :+ editVowel2
      }
      else {
        revSoundList2 = revSoundList2 :+ sound2
      }
    }
    if(revSoundList1 == revSoundList2){
      true
    }
    else{
      false
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by question?@Robby Cornelissen

Comment: I hope this `Bot123224` username is not a subtle hint for the fact that this is all part of Turing-NLG community conversation experiments.

Comment: This is a Q&A site. The idea is to ask questions and (hopefully) get answers. You didn't ask a question.

Comment: I did I need help with writing a method for rhyming!

Comment: I did have an approach with some scrap code but i can’t seem to put it in the textbox without formatting error

Comment: The part I’m confused the most is looping up until the first vowel and nothing after it. I’m not sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think reversing is necessary.

```
def isRhyme(sndA :List[String], sndB :List[String]) :Boolean = {
  val vowel = "[AEIOUY]+".r
  sndA.foldLeft(""){case (res, s) => vowel.findPrefixOf(s).getOrElse(res+s)} ==
    sndB.foldLeft(""){case (res, s) => vowel.findPrefixOf(s).getOrElse(res+s)}
}
```

---

### explanation

- `"[AEIOUY]+".r` - This is a Regular Expression (that's the `.r` part) that means "a `String` of one or more of these characters." In other words, any combination of capital letter vowels.
- `findPrefixOf()` - This returns the first part of the test string that matches the regular expression. So `vowel.findPrefixOf("AY2")` returns `Some("AY")` because the first two letters match the regular expression. And `vowel.findPrefixOf("OFF")` returns `Some("O")` because only the first letter matches the regular expression. But `vowel.findPrefixOf("BAY")` returns `None` because the string does not start with any of the specified characters.
- `getOrElse()` - This unwraps an `Option`. So `Some("AY").getOrElse("X")` returns `"AY"`, and `Some("O").getOrElse("X")` returns `"O"`, but `None.getOrElse("X")` returns `"X"` because there's nothing inside a `None` value so we go with the OrElse default return value.
- `foldLeft()()` - This takes a collection of elements and, starting from the "left", it "folds" them in on each other until a final result is obtained.

So, consider how `List("HH", "AE1", "F", "JH", "IY1", "P")` would be processed.

```
res    s     result
===    ===   ======
""     HH    ""+HH   //s doesn't match the RE so default res+s
HH     AE1   AE      //s does match the RE, use only the matching part
AE     F     AE+F    //res+s
AEF    JH    AEF+JH  //res+s
AEFJH  IY1   IY      //only the matching part
IY     P     IY+P    //res+s

final result: "IYP"
```

Comment: Could you write the code in simpler terms since I’m only a beginner at scala as you can tell from my code. Sorry :(

Comment: If it is the 'fold' / 'foldLeft' which is seems confusing to you I think it is worth reading its documentation and learning how to use it, as it is something you will find a lot in a typical Scala code.

Comment: @jwvh I really appreciate your help. Thank You, but can you add some explanation below that code so I can see what’s happening I’ve read up on foldleft but still seem unsure what’s happening here.

Comment: Is `option.fold(res+s)(identity)` the same as `option.getOrElse(res +s)`? If it is, would not `getOrElse` be a more natural and easier to read?